# Бинарный поиск итеративным методом

Tags: c#, циклы

сделал программу бинарного поиска через цикл итерациями, как я понял можно ускорить поиск если внести некоторые изменения
В коде выделил что и как я предполагаю можно изменить для ускорения, подскажите пожалуйста прав или нет? вроде программа работает

Подскажите пожалуйста как переделать условные операции, с помощью них же можно ускорить алгоритм?

```
    public static int BinarySearchWhile(int desiredValue, int[] array)
    {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.Length; // правильно ли я понимаю что здесь границу поиска можно/нужно сделать array.Length - 1 ?

        while (left < right) // здесь возможно для ускорения сделать так left <= right ??
        {
            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;

            if (array[middle] == desiredValue)
            {
                return middle;
            }

            if (array[middle] > desiredValue)
            {
                right = middle; // здесь точнее будет middle - 1 ??
            }
            else
            {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int BinarySearchTree<T>(T[] array, int left, int right, T key) where T: IComparable
{
    while (left <= right)
    {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;

        switch (key.CompareTo(array[middle]))
        {
            case 0:
                return middle;
            case 1:
                right = middle - 1;
                break;
            case -1:
                left = middle + 1;
                break;
        };
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Вызов

```
 int[] mass = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

 var result = Search.BinarySearchTree(mass, 0, mass.Length - 1, 9);
```

Comment: Денис, Спасибо большое за ответ!
А если я конструкцию в switch заменю на if? это ускорит? или я прост о вернусь к исходному вариант? 

может быть есть ещё какие то варианты но без key.CompareTo?

Comment: @IgorM, свитч быстрее потому что эту не надо нечего решать - пришло значение - переключился на него - выполнил действие, в случае ифа - надо что-то с чем-то сравнить.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения! Скажите пожалуйста Можно ли key.CompareTo заменить на что проще?

Comment: @IgorM, только сравнением >, <, ==, либо как написал я. Возможно, как то можно еще, но в голову идет только такие 2 решения.